# Jquery, Show hide related link on the basis of clicked name

Tags: jquery, show-hide

My HTML, which renders the clickable link and related details, is:

```
<ul class="topindex">
    <li>
        <h4><a title="A folder" href="#A-folder" rel="nofollow" class="index-letters">A</a></h4>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h4><a title="B folder" href="#B-folder" rel="nofollow" class="index-letters">B</a></h4>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h4><a title="C folder" href="#C-folder" rel="nofollow" class="index-letters">C</a></h4>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h4><a title="D folder" href="#D-folder" rel="nofollow" class="index-letters">D</a></h4>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul class="index-list">
    <li><a name="A-folder" id="A-folder"></a>
        <h5><a title="Back to index" href="#tags_top" rel="nofollow">A</a></h5>

        <ul class="links">
            <li class="cat-item"><a href="http://www.related.link" title="A" rel="nofollow">A text</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a name="B-folder" id="B-folder"></a>
        <h5><a title="Back to index" href="#tags_top" rel="nofollow">B</a></h5>

        <ul class="links">
            <li class="cat-item"><a href="http://www.related.link" title="B" rel="nofollow">B text</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a name="C-folder" id="C-folder"></a>
        <h5><a title="Back to index" href="#tags_top" rel="nofollow">C</a></h5>

        <ul class="links">
            <li class="cat-item"><a href="http://www.related.link" title="C" rel="nofollow">C text</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

My target is to hide all `li`s initially and show the details only when the alphabetic link is clicked.

I have tried the below code, but it does not work. I.e it does not show and hide the sections when the links are clicked.

```
 $('.index-list li').hide();
    $("a.index-letters").click(function() {
    $('.index-list li').hide();
    $('#'+$(this).attr('name')).show();   
 });
```

I would appreciate any assistance on this.

Thank you.

Comment: Which `divs`??? and I think you misunderstood a little bit the `<a>` tag

Comment: updated the code, it should be li not div , sorry

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
$('.index-list li').hide();

$("a.index-letters").click(function() {
  $('.index-list li').hide();
  $($(this).attr('href')).parent('li').show();   
});
```

Look at the line above: `$($(this).attr('href')).parent('li').show();`

You should get the content of the `href` attribute of what you click. This is were you have stored the `id` you are looking for. There is no `name` attribute as you are trying to reach.

Also, when you then reach this `a` with the correct `id`, then you need to show its *parent*, the `li`, not *itself*. It is the parent `li` that was initially hidden.

Comment: I am trying to get the id of <li><a name="B-folder" id="B-folder"></a><h5><a title="Back to index" href="#tags_top" rel="nofollow">B</a></h5>. the show or hide this li accordingly

Comment: With `$(this).attr('name')` you are using the `name` of what you just clicked, not the `id`.

Comment: I am not sure if my jquery approach is correct but my object is to show hide .index-list's child li on when related alphabet is clicked.

Comment: I can see I misunderstood in the beginning. See my changed answer. This should fit?

Comment: It does work but partially, it shows only the index letter but not the contents, i.e it will show "C" letter but not "C text"